# SOAP PHP - SimpleType error response

Tags: php, web-services, soap

i've a problem with a response of my SOAP webservice.

I've this structure:

```
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="sesso">
    <xsd:simpleType>
         <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="M" />
            <xsd:enumeration value="F" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:element>
```

And i need that my response is:

```
<sesso xsi:type="xsd:string">M</sesso>
```

But I always get a ns1:sesso type:

```
<sesso xsi:type="ns1:sesso">M</sesso>
```

Why this?

My php code is simply this one:

```
$server = new SoapServer("assistiti.wsdl", array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2));
$server->addFunction("aggiornaAssistiti");
$server->handle();

function aggiornaAssistiti() {
$assistito = new stdClass();

$assistito->sesso = "M";

return $assistito; }
```

(i'm using soapUI for the tests)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [SoapVar](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapvar.php). Third parameter specifies the type.

Comment: It works!! Thankyou so much! :D

I used: $assistito->sesso = new SoapVar(myValue, XSD_STRING);